# Failing to build SwiftUI with more than 2 ForEach statements

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I'm receiving the following error when I try and build an Xcode project using SwiftUI.

The error I get is "The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions"

I have tried to remove a lot of the complexities of the code to simplify it down as much as possible. I also tried reducing the number of lines of Picker's to test whether that was the issues.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    // set child name
    @State private var childName: String = ""
    // set the days of the week
    let daysOfWeek = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"]

    // set empty
    @State private var selectedAttendance: String = ""
    let attendance = ["None", "All Day", "AM", "PM"]
    @State private var mondayAttendance = 0
    @State private var tuesdayAttendance = 0
    @State private var wednesdayAttendance = 0
    @State private var thursdayAttendance = 0
    @State private var fridayAttendance = 0

    @State private var selectedProvider = 0
    let providers = ["School 1", "School 2", "School 3", "School 4", "School 5"]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("Your Child's Details")) {
                    TextField("Name", text: $childName)
                }

                // PICKER to choose childcare provider
                Section(header: Text("Who looks after your child?")) {
                    Picker("Childcare Provider", selection: $selectedProvider) {
                        ForEach(0 ..< providers.count) {
                            Text("\(self.providers[$0])")
                        }
                    }
                }


                Section(header: Text("Which days does your child attend?")) {
                    VStack {

                        // Monday
                        HStack {
                            Text("Monday")
                                .dayOfWeek()
                            Picker("Monday", selection: $mondayAttendance) {
                                ForEach(0 ..< 4) {
                                    Text("\(self.attendance[$0])")
                                }
                            }
                            .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                        }

                        // Tuesday
                        HStack {
                            Text("Tuesday")
                                .dayOfWeek()
                            Picker("Tuesday", selection: $tuesdayAttendance) {
                                ForEach(0 ..< 4) {
                                    Text("\(self.attendance[$0])")
                                }
                            }
                            .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                        }
//
//                        // Wednesday
//                        HStack {
//                            Text("Wednesday")
//                                .dayOfWeek()
//                            Picker("Wednesday", selection: $wednesdayAttendance) {
//                                ForEach(0 ..< 4) {
//                                    Text("\(self.attendance[$0])")
//                                }
//                            }
//                            .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
//                        }


                    }


                }

            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Your Child")
        }

    }
}
```

When I try and build with just "Monday" and "Tuesday" showing, it works. As soon as I uncomment Wednesday (or more), the build fails and I get the error.

I understand that I need to simplify the code, but it's pretty simple already and I'm not sure where to take it next.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with `For Each`.  Where is the definition of `dayOfWeek()` that is attached to Text.  It should return a view. It should have failed even with one `For Each` as it had `dayOfWeek()`.  Probably that modifier might have been defined in your app.

Comment: Thanks - I have defined `dayOfWeek()` in a separate swift file as this is the formatting for Text. It really only declares a width.

Comment: It was working for me with three `ForEach` statements.  Probably you can share `dayOfWeek`.  Also I was using `Version 11.2.1 (11B53)` of XCode.

Comment: I ran into this issue multiple times.  It is not necessarily the line at failure happens, is the issue.  Issue might be in a different line.

Comment: I haven't been able to find an answer, but have moved to using the List view which changes the way data is populated. It works for now. Perhaps I'll have this issue again in the future.